# "Amount" field not passing through to PayPal

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, e-commerce

I'm developing a site for a non-profit client that includes a custom donation form. The form includes options for the user to select a pre-defined donation amount, or enter their own amount, and then click "donate," which takes them to PayPal. I've confirmed that the actual donate button works via three successful tests through my Sandbox accounts. I also am able to confirm that the custom form correctly calculates the selected amounts and populates the value of the "amount" field because I'm able to log those results in the console. The "amount" field, as best I can tell, is in line with PayPal's guidelines. However, the amount will not pass through to PayPal.

The code for the front end:

```
<div id="main-donate-container" class="form_container">
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
          <div id="small-button-container" class="">
             <div id="twenty-five" class="lightred general_button blue_button form_small_button selected_amount select_state_color_btn"><span>25</span></div>
             <div id="fifty" class="general_button blue_button form_small_button select_state_color_btn"><span>50</span></div>
             <div id="one-hundred" class="general_button blue_button form_small_button select_state_color_btn"><span>100</span></div>
             <div id="two-hundred" class="general_button blue_button form_small_button select_state_color_btn"><span>200</span></div>
          </div>
          <div id="other-amount" class="general_button blue_button form_other_amount">
             <span><img src="<?php $root ?>/images/close.png"/></span>
             <label>$</label><input class="whitetext" type="text" name="other-amount" value="143">
          </div>
          <div id="other-amount-button" class="general_button blue_button select_state_color_btn">
              <span>OTHER</span>
          </div>
          <input id="donation-amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="">                            
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="(PayPal key here)">
          <input type="submit" class="general_button blue_button submit_button" id="submit" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" value="Donate!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
</div> <!-- end main donate container -->
```

And the JavaScript behind the scenes:

```
//initialize variables to track donation amounts    
var donation_amount = 25;
var previous_donation = 0;

//format the amounts displayed in buttons as US currency
$('#donate-content .form_small_button span').formatCurrency({roundToDecimalPlace:0});


$('#donate-content #other-amount-button').on('click',function(){
        //save the previously selected donation amount in case use cancels out of "other"
        previous_donation = donation_amount;
        //set new donation amount to the default "other" amount
        donation_amount = $('#other-amount input').val();
        //change background of other button and other amount field to #FFB310 and show the other amount field
        $(this).css('background-color','#BB6098');
        $('#donate-content #other-amount').css('background-color','#BB6098').show();
        $('#donate-content #other-amount-button').addClass('selected_amount');
        //format the amounts displayed in other amount field for US currency
        $('#donate-content #other-amount input').formatCurrency({symbol:'',roundToDecimalPlace:0});
        $('#donate-content #other-amount input').select();
    });

$('#donate-content #other-amount span').on('click',function(){
        donation_amount = previous_donation;
        $('#donate-content #other-amount-button').css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)').removeClass('selected_amount');;
        $('#donate-content #other-amount').hide();
        $('#donate-content #other-amount input').val('143');
    }); 

$('#donate-content #other-amount input').keyup(function(){
        donation_amount = $(this).val();
    });

$('#donate-content #other-amount input').keypress(function(event){
        return isNumber(event);
    });

$('#donate-content #twenty-five').on('click',function(){
        $('#donate-content .select_state_color_btn').css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)').removeClass('selected_amount');
        $(this).addClass('selected_amount').css('background-color','#C25252');
        donation_amount = $(this).text();
        donation_amount = donation_amount.slice(1);
    });

$('#donate-content #fifty').on('click',function(){
        $('#donate-content .select_state_color_btn').css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)').removeClass('selected_amount');
        $(this).addClass('selected_amount').css('background-color','#CA9859');
        donation_amount = $(this).text();
        donation_amount = donation_amount.slice(1);
    });

$('#donate-content #one-hundred').on('click',function(){
        $('#donate-content .select_state_color_btn').css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)').removeClass('selected_amount');
        $(this).addClass('selected_amount').css('background-color','#7E0B80');  
        donation_amount = $(this).text();
        donation_amount = donation_amount.slice(1);
    });

$('#donate-content #two-hundred').on('click',function(){
        $('#donate-content .select_state_color_btn').css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)').removeClass('selected_amount');
        $(this).addClass('selected_amount').css('background-color','#59ABB7');  
        donation_amount = $(this).text();
        donation_amount = donation_amount.slice(1);
    });

$('#donate-content .select_state_color_btn').hover(
function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected_amount')){
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }
            else{   
            $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
        }
    },
function(){

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected_amount')){
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }
            else{

            $(this).css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)');
            }

        });

$('#donate-content #other-amount-button').hover(
function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected_amount')){
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }
            else{   
            $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');     }
    },
function(){

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected_amount')){
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }
            else{   
            $(this).css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)');
            }

        });


$('#donate-content #submit').hover(
function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','#96BA5F');
    },
function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','rgba(67, 80, 164, .9)');    
        });

$('#donate-content #submit').on('click',function(e){
        $('#donate-content #donation-amount').val(donation_amount);
```

Can anyone point what I'm sure is the small detail that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I've made certain that the "amount" variable has been added to the hosted button on PayPal's end, but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it turns out that hosted PayPal buttons won't accept the "amount" custom field. In order to make this function, a non-hosted button has to be used. The end result was generating a non-hosted button from PayPal, the result of which looks like this in the front end code (the JavaScript stays the same):

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="(Place you PayPal key here)">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Charity">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="(Your success URL here)">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="(Your cancel landing URL here)">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input id="donation-amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="">                       
    <input type="submit" class="general_button blue_button submit_button" id="submit" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" value="Donate!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```